# Localized app name does appears in English only via App Store app on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, ios12

I have a weird issues. There is my app which I localized for multiple languages following Apple guidelines. All works well, app reacts to the language on the phone, I can see localized app name by using App Store via VPN to some country, etc.

However, when I switch phone to German, for example, switch App Store app to Germany, and then search my app via its German name, app store finds it, but **displays its name in German**.

I am not sure why this is happening only via App Store app on the iphone itself.

Did anyone have such problems and how did you solve them?